# I am trying to use and free 2 pointers in a Delphi Function. How do I free them properly?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3. I am trying to learn more about how to properly use and then free the pointers. I have two pointers lpParams and pHolder. I would like to know if I must used a typed pointer for pHolder and what the proper way to free both pinters in this routine. Thank you.

```
function TmyLine.LineOpen(dwLineDevice:        Integer;
                             var wMediaMode:  Integer;
                             phLine,
                             plTAPIVersion:       pLongInt): Integer;
  var lOwnership,
      lResult:            LongInt;
      lpParams:     pTLineCallparams;  // first pointer
      pHolder:      Pointer;                        // second pointer
      dwAddressID, dwMediaMode: DWORD;  
begin
  if not bDeviceInitialized then
    lResult := -1
  else
    begin
      pHolder := nil; // default is nil unless we are using the singleaddress method
      lOwnership := 0;
      if FPrivilege.bSingleAddress then
      begin
        lOwnership := lOwnership + LINEOPENOPTION_SINGLEADDRESS;  
        try
          lpParams := AllocMem(SizeOf(TLineCallParams) + 128);   // make up a big enough value
        except
          lpParams := nil;
          exit; // should I exit here? what about if there is an error? do I free pHolder?
        end;
        lpParams.dwTotalSize := sizeof(TLineCallParams) + 128;

        lpParams.dwAddressMode := LINEADDRESSMODE_ADDRESSID;
        pHolder := lpParams;     // is this ok? Do i need a typed pointer?
      end;

      lResult := lineOpen(Fline.hLineApp,       // fnd 64bit, see if longint needs to be dword_ptr
                          dwLineDevice,
                          phLine,
                          plTAPIVersion^,
                          FTAPI.lExtVersion,
                          DWORD_PTR(Self),  //Pointer to the control, it is passed to the Callback routine as the lCallBackInstance parameter
                          lOwnership,
                          wMediaMode,
                          pHolder);    // using the pointer here
      if lResult <> 0  then
        begin
          pHolder := nil;
          lpParams := nil; // is the the right way to do this?

          end
      else
        begin       
          lineSetStatusMessages(temp);
        end;
    end;

  pHolder := nil; //  is this the correct way to free things up?
  if lpParams <> nil then freemem(lpParams, sizeof(TLineCallParams) + 128); 
  LineOpen := lResult;
end;
```

Comment: There are many problems here. It's hard to know what to focus on. Especially as we don't know anything about the API you are calling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Every call to AllocMem should have a respective call to FreeMem, otherwise, it is a leak

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Yes indeed. But the rest of the code in the question is full of problems.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In this case, I think we should just limit ourselves to answer OP's question. IMO, the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @David: `lineOpen` is a Telephony API (TAPI) function from Win32 (Tapi32.dll).

Comment: I reverted your edit. If you want to ask a specific follow up to Remy's answer, please do so in comments. A small clarification could be added to the question. Doubling the size of the question with a whole new chunk of code isn't appropriate. In my view, you need to step back and find a way to ask a short, concise, and focused question.

Comment: Please stop asking new questions here. A new question is, a new question. But your way of asking is poor. If you want someone to review your code, go to the code review se site.

Comment: I've reverted your edit yet again. If you insist on defacing your original question by changing it to a totally different one, I'm going to flag this for a moderator's attention and we'll let them deal with your inappropriate conduct. **DO NOT** put your last edit back again. @DavidHeffernan has already explained your edit is not proper. You should pay heed to the advice (and warning) here.

Comment: Ken, Despite reading the site instructions, I could not determine how to edit appropriately. It was an honest mistake. I am a rare poster. I did not notice the "more comments" link to see that David "reverted" my code.  I thought it wasn't saving. I appreciate the help but neither yours or Davids comment were instructive. I can't add, "ok, like this?". I must just create a new question? Is it that the first question was specific to pointers and I was wanting too much detail about the code and where it was created and freed? What is the "code review site"? Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't add a new question to this question. If you now have a different question, post it as a new one. Changing your existing question drastically after you've received an answer to it is not appropriate. In some cases, it can invalidate the answers and even make them wrong (which causes the person who posted the answer look foolish and can even garner them downvotes on their answer). David's [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130799/i-am-trying-to-use-and-free-2-pointers-in-a-delphi-function-how-do-i-free-them#comment46524685_29130799) explains what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are filling in the `dwAddressMode` field, but you are not filling in the `dwAddressID` field.  You need to fill in the `dwAddressID` or else there is no point in using `LINEOPENOPTION_SINGLEADDRESS`.

Second, `lineOpen()` does not take ownership of the `LINECALLPARAMS` pointer that you pass to it.  You must deallocate the memory yourself after `lineOpen()` exits, regardless of its result, eg:

```
function TmyLine.LineOpen(dwLineDevice: Integer;
                         var wMediaMode: Integer;
                         phLine,
                         plTAPIVersion: pLongInt): Integer;
var
  lOwnership: DWORD;
  lpParams: pTLineCallparams;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if not bDeviceInitialized then Exit;

  lOwnership := 0;

  lpParams := nil;
  try
    if FPrivilege.bSingleAddress then
    begin
      try
        lpParams := AllocMem(SizeOf(TLineCallParams));
      except
        Exit;
      end;

      lpParams.dwTotalSize := sizeof(TLineCallParams);
      lpParams.dwAddressID := ...; // don't forget to fill this in!
      lpParams.dwAddressMode := LINEADDRESSMODE_ADDRESSID;

      lOwnership := LINEOPENOPTION_SINGLEADDRESS;  
    end;

    Result := lineOpen(Fline.hLineApp,
                      dwLineDevice,
                      phLine,
                      plTAPIVersion^,
                      FTAPI.lExtVersion,
                      DWORD_PTR(Self),
                      lOwnership,
                      wMediaMode,
                      lpParams);
  finally
    if lpParams <> nil then
      FreeMem(lpParams, sizeof(TLineCallParams)); 
  end;

  if Result = 0 then
    lineSetStatusMessages(...);
end;
```

Third, since you are only filling in standard fields of `LINECALLPARAMS` and not any extensions, you don't really need to dynamically allocate the `LINECALLPARAMS` on the heap at all.  You can alternatively allocate it statically on the stack instead (which is why `lineOpen()` cannot take ownership of it), eg:

```
function TmyLine.LineOpen(dwLineDevice: Integer;
                         var wMediaMode: Integer;
                         phLine,
                         plTAPIVersion: pLongInt): Integer;
var
  lOwnership: DWORD;
  Params: TLineCallparams;
  lpParams: pTLineCallparams;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if not bDeviceInitialized then Exit;

  lOwnership := 0;
  lpParams := nil;

  if FPrivilege.bSingleAddress then
  begin
    Params.dwTotalSize := sizeof(TLineCallParams);
    Params.dwAddressID := ...; // don't forget to fill this in!
    Params.dwAddressMode := LINEADDRESSMODE_ADDRESSID;

    lpParams := @Params;
    lOwnership := LINEOPENOPTION_SINGLEADDRESS;  
  end;

  Result := lineOpen(Fline.hLineApp,
                    dwLineDevice,
                    phLine,
                    plTAPIVersion^,
                    FTAPI.lExtVersion,
                    DWORD_PTR(Self),
                    lOwnership,
                    wMediaMode,
                    lpParams);
  if Result = 0 then
    lineSetStatusMessages(...);
end;
```

Comment: The first version can return without setting `Result`. FWIW, I think you should dissuade the asker from dealling with out of memory errors in that way. The exception should not be trapped here.

Comment: @Remy, I want to add code, do I edit my original post? I can't see how to continue a thread and say, ok ignore the previous code, how about this...

Comment: @F.Decker: you can edit the original question, if the new code is related to the original question.  Otherwise post it as a new question.

Comment: Remy and @DavidHeffernan, I made an edit to the first post and changed the code. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I am lost. When I look here at my post, the code above where I edited for final review is not there. But under it I see "edited by David Hefernan". When I click on that, it takes me to another page where the code I am asking for help with displays. I must have posted it more than once because I did not see it appear, two of the posts are redlined and the final version is there. Does a moderator have to approve it or something?

Comment: Ok, it dispays now, I clicked on "rollback" to select the correct one. I believe that is what I had to do.